27" iMac 5k VDH002, won't mount other disks
2015 27" iMac 5k with SDD. Diagnostic says "VDH002 issue with storage device" and it won't boot from the internal drive any more. Recovery can't mount any other disks to reinstall.
Luckily I had an external SSD already prepared, but booting to it is very slow.
Once booted, I can mount using hdiutil in the terminal but not using the Finder.
This applies to DMGs and physical disks, so I am able to boot to recovery partition but not run the OSX Install, since it has to mount disks. Disk Utility does not show the disk.
Because the 27" iMac is so difficult to open up, I am not keen to replace internal components.
Is there anything I can do to further diagnose or work around this without taking it apart?
Can I repair or at least deactivate the internal drive so it doesn't keep breaking Disk Image Mounter?
